# Iterate over all elements of custom node of linkedlist

Tags: c#

I am having a class node like this :

```
 class Node
    {
        public int node;
        public int weight;
    }
```

Also am having an array of LinkedList of n nodes like this :

```
LinkedList<Node>[] Adj = new LinkedList<Node>[n];
```

How can I access elements of ith element of the array Adj. I want to access nodes and weights of LinkedList elements present in list corresponding to ith element of array Adj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the array elements using an indexer e.g. Adj[i]

In order to access all Nodes in the Linked List at Adj[i] you can use an IEnumerable E.g.

```
List<Node> nodes = Adj[i].ToList();
```

You can then run a for loop on the list "**nodes**".